# Twitter bootstrap interferes with combobox

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

Twitter bootstrap has `.dropdown-menu` class and the combobox library I use has a class `.combobox .dropdown-menu` which twitter bootstrap makes unusable.

Can I somehow from my own CSS file fix this?

Worst case I can change the twitter bootstrap css, I tried this but it didnt work

```
.dropdown-menu:not(.combobox .dropdown-menu) {
}
```

Comment: add a div having class on top of your dropdown element and then use that class context to define your own css. (you might want to use !important in case it doesnt override)

Comment: Which "combobox library" ?

Comment: https://github.com/AndersMalmgren/Knockout.Combobox